# Active Directory extensionattribute update in bulk from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm working towards making changes to over 3000 users in Active Directory. Each one needs to have 3 additions made to there attributes section extensionAttribute3, extensionAttribute4, and extensionAttribute5. Can someone help me with a command line entry that accesses a CSV and fills in the information based on the information in the CSV?

Here is what I currently hve in the CSV:

```
samAccountName  ExtensionAttribute3 ExtensionAttribute4 ExtensionAttribute5
```

And this is my code:

```
Import-Csv c:\scripts\updatecsv.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName `
    -ObjectAttributes @{ExtensionAttribute3=($_.ExtensionAttribute3); ExtensionAttribute4=($_.ExtensionAttribute4)}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? While we'll help you with your code, we won't write it for you entirely.

Comment: Import-Csv c:\scripts\updatecsv.csv | ForEach-Object {
Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName `
-ObjectAttributes @{ExtensionAttribute3=($_.ExtensionAttribute3);
ExtensionAttribute4=($_.ExtensionAttribute4)}
}

Comment: Please update your question with your code, don't just put it in a comment. Also, give any errors that you get when running the code.

Comment: Actually, have you even done a `Get-Help Set-ADUser -detailed` yet? I don't think so, because `-ObjectAttribute` is not a valid parameter for that command.

Comment: Honestly, No I didn't as I did a google search and came up with that code from stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the non-existing `ObjectAttributes` parameter, try using `Replace`:

```
Import-Csv .\updatecsv.csv |ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -Replace @{
        ExtensionAttribute3 = $_.ExtensionAttribute3
        ExtensionAttribute4 = $_.ExtensionAttribute4
        ExtensionAttribute5 = $_.ExtensionAttribute5
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to get him to figure out for himself rather than just running to us asking for help without really even trying.